# Django ContentTypes convert uuid field to integer field

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a situation where `object_id` for `ForeignKey` accepts a `PositiveIntegerField` but all `id's` of my models are set as `uuid` .

I looked up the documentation and found that i should use `get_prep_value(value)` or `get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared=False)¶`

The question is how should i exactly do it?

Here is the code of model that contains the `foreignRelation`

```
target_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='target_obj',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,
                                        blank=True,
                                        db_index=True)
target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                  db_index=True)
```

Field from all other models

```
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Whenever i try to save the model with the current setting i get this error

> django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make it a `UUIDField` as well:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    target_ct = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='target_obj',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    target_id = models.UUIDField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

Then you this can refer to all objects that have a `UUIDField` as primary key.

Exactly this is however one of the reasons why it is often better to use an `AutoField` as primary key: if all models have the same primary key you can refer to all objects with this. Now with this you can only refer to models with a `UUIDField` as primary key.

Comment: I've tried it, i'm getting this error when i try to migrate it as a uuid field `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to uuid
LINE 1: ..." ALTER COLUMN "target_id" TYPE uuid USING "target_id"::uuid`

Comment: @h1dd3n: the problem is that you can not alter the column type. You probably better first delete the column, make a migration, and then add a new column.